# Web Crawler with BS4 and a Show more button

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am using Beautiful Soup 4 for my web crawler and I am trying to go through [tasty website](https://tasty.co/topic/best-vegetarian).

It has a show more `button` instead of pages and I am trying to figure out how to do this **without Selenium**.

I looked through the API source code for the show more button & I think I have found the JSON it is: `from= 100&in_unit=true&primary_terms` etc.

I am not sure how I would implement this in my code.

I think I would use to begin with:

```
data = requests.get(url.format(page)).json()
```

but not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are heading for the API approach you are close to it.

**Minimal example**

```
import requests, json

size = 50
start = 0
searchTerm = 'vegetarian'   

response = requests.get('https://tasty.co/api/recipes/search?size={0}&from={1}&primary_terms={2}'.format(size, start, searchTerm))

print(*[item['name'] for item in response.json()['items']], sep = "\n")
```

**Output**

```
Delicious Soups For Every Mood
8 Berry-licious Breakfast Recipes 
8 Fun and Easy Bake Sale Recipes
Choco Chip Cookies
Light Sweet Potato Cake
Savoury Cheese Crackers
Fiery Fries
Sweet And Sour Eggplant
Zesty Artichoke Basil Grain Bowl
Bell Pepper Chutney
Sungyi&#x27;s S’mores Cookies
Hearty Onion Dip And Chips
Pizza Margherita by Mario Batali
Tofu Buddha Bowl
Browned “Butter” Chocolate Chip Cookies
The Best Pumpkin Pancakes
2-ingredient Pasta
Breyers® Ice Cream Tea Party
3 Savory Vegetarian Holiday Mains 
4 Easy Recipes To Help You Go Vegan
...
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you did. I’m pretty new to python, so would you just change the 20 to like infinite or just a really high number to display the items after the show more button?

Comment: In fact that you are new, you should grab this tiny example and try it on your own to learn how things working and the result will be affected - Any way I edited and set `size` to `50` cause `infinity` wont be the best idea ;)

Comment: Thank you, I'm still working on trying to make it work. I appreciate the help!